# Asp.MVC and WCF mixed authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf, authorization

I've got WCF web services hosted in an ASP.NET application. For the asp.net
part I'm using Forms authentication for the web services I want to use
Windows authentication. After configuring this the caller of the
service is getting redirected to the login page of the web app. I have tried to
exclude the folder hosting the WCF web services but could not get it working.

Can this be configured or do I have to host my WCF as separate site in iis?

**Edit**

After some more googling I found that its is posible but its not as easy as i would like it to be :) The part I especialy dislike is that my app has to have this wrapper in GC or app has to have full trust permisions :(

http://mvolo.com/blogs/serverside/archive/2008/02/11/IIS-7.0-Two_2D00_Level-Authentication-with-Forms-Authentication-and-Windows-Authentication.aspx

Ill try it and let you know how it went.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I googled works, but Im not going to use it because application I made is not supposed to have full trust permisions and I also dont want to place the wrapper in GAC. So the solution I ended up with is split WS and asp.mvc app into two sites on iis.

Answer (score 0):

Did you setup your WCF bindings correctly in the web.config?

Here's a link on how to configure this:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WCF/WCFBasicHttpBinding.aspx

Comment: Well I need to use both forms authentification for asp.mvc app and then at the same time windows for ws. I need to separate these two somehow if its even posible...

Comment: I'm not sure this will work then. The problem lies in the authentication settings directly on the IIS virtual directory for the web application. When using windows authentication in WCF, the IIS virtual directory needs to enable windows authentication and turn off anonymous access; but ASP.NET webforms using forms authentication, requires the IIS virtual directory to have "anonymous access" turned on. The two modes conflict with each other. I'm not sure how you would go about resolving that conflict.

Comment: There is a wokaround look at my post I edited it. Eaven I dont like the solution provided Ill try it...

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the ASP.NET compatibility mode disabled for the WCF Services ?. If it's enabled, ASP.NET will try to authenticate the user first. Otherwise, it should go straigh to WCF.